# Redux Toolkit: How to refer action created with createAction as type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Redux toolkit provides `createAction` helper method. I am having trouble referring actions created with `createAction` as type.

**For example**:

```
const getData = createAction<PayloadAction<number>>('user/getData')

function* exampleSaga(action: ?) {
   ...
}
```

How can I tell *`exampleSaga`* that `action` is of type **`getData`**?

---

To see how I've tried doing it, refer the below (example) code and see comments for the problem I am facing:

*reducer.ts*

```
import { createAction, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getData = createAction<PayloadAction<number>>('user/getData');

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: userSliceName,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getUser(state: IUserState): void {
      state.loading = true;
      state.error = null;
    },
    getUserSuccess(state: IUserState, action: PayloadAction<{ user: IUser }>): void {
      const { user } = action.payload;
      state.user = user;
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = null;
    },
    getUserFailure(state: IUserState, action: PayloadAction<string>): void {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export type UserSaga = Generator<
  | CallEffect<IUser>
  | PutEffect<typeof getUserSuccess>
  | PutEffect<typeof getUserFailure>
  | ForkEffect<never>
>;
```

*sagas.ts*

```
import { UserSaga, getData } from './reducer.ts';

// For the following fetchUser saga arguments, how can I define that 'action' is of type getData, imported from the above 'reducer.ts' file.
function* fetchUser(action: PayloadAction<typeof getData>): UserSaga {
  try {
    const userId = action.payload;
    // Problem is here
    // I expect userId to be of type number, whereas it is:
    // ActionCreatorWithPayload<{payload: number, type: string}>
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    ...
  }
}

function* userSaga(): UserSaga {
  const pattern: any = getData.type;
  yield takeLatest(pattern, fetchUser);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I did some more digging and here's how I got around the issue.

An action could be created without tying it to a **SliceCaseReducer**: (Note that the created `getData` below is not an **Action** per se rather an **ActionCreator**).

*common.ts*

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const getData = createAction<number>('getData');
```

`getData` is already cooked to be dispatched from a FunctionComponent if given the correct payload:

*component.tsx*

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { getData } from './state/common';

const User: React.FC = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const { userId } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect((): void => {
    dispatch(getData(Number(userId)));
  }, []);

  return (<>User Component</>);
};

export default UserContainer;
```

### With Sagas

#### To have a saga listen to the action

Saga Effects accept string type of an action to react. Luckily, **actionCreator**s expose a **type** property representing the defined string name of the action.

*saga.ts* (listener)

```
import { takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { getData } from './common';

function* userSaga() {
  // getData.type could be input to a Saga Effect
  yield takeLatest(getData.type, fetchUser); // fetchUser is a worker saga explained below
}
```

#### Specifying action as argument of a saga.

Specifying the action as argument to a saga is a bit tricky, we have to use TypeScript's [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Interestingly, it's mentioned in the redux-toolkit's [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#actioncreatormatch) as well. In short, we have to use `actionCreator.match` method of the actionCreator to discriminate down the passed action to the desired type. Thus, after discrimination, we receive the desired static typing for the matched action's payload.

*saga.ts* (worker)

```
import { Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as userApi from '../../../api/user-api';
import { getData } from './common';
import { getUserSuccess, getUserFailure } from './user';

// Note that we can't directly specify that fetchUser only accepts getData action type.
function* fetchUser(action: Action) {
  try {
    // getData.match could be used to assert that we are only concerned with getData action type
    if (getData.match(action)) {
      // Inside the body of if, we get correct static typing
      const userId = action.payload;

      const fetchedUser = yield call(userApi.getUser, userId);
      yield put(getUserSuccess({user: fetchedUser}));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(getUserFailure(e.message));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is how you will get it using return type of your getData.

```
function* exampleSaga(action: ReturnType<typeof getData>) {

...

}
```